# Installing Hpricot on Ruby 1.9.1 on Windows

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I am trying to install hpricot using the command:

```
>gem install hpricot -v 0.8.2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing hpricot:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for stdio.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:362:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:431:in`try_cpp'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:809:in `block in have_header'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:668:in`block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:248:in`open'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:274:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:248:in`open'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:270:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:667:in`checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:808:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:2:in`'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hpricot-0.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hpricot-0.8.2/ext/fast_xs/gem_make.out

it mentions I need to install "development tools" but I have no idea what that refers to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try installing the windows ruby devkit (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). This will give you the MinGW compiler which MIGHT overcome your problem.

Comment: next step is for you to provide an accepted answer to your own question

Comment: You need to install ruby-dev. It is a development tools [Visit this link to download to Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856087/sudo-apt-get-install-ruby-dev-in-windows)

Answer (score 54):

Try:

```
gem install hpricot --platform=mswin32
```

Comment: Worked great for me, and I was worried I was in for a world of hurt.  Now trying to get libxml to work!

Comment: I was having the same problem, and this being the first solution that I tried; worked like a charm! I love stack overflow. Thanks for the great answer freek!

However, for my own curiosity, does mswin32 means 32-bit windows? If I have 64 bit 7 pro, should I (next time) type mswin64? Sorry, just curious.

Answer (score 6):

Install the devkit at rubyinstaller.org/downloads

Answer (score 4):

Execute below command and it works:

```
gem install hpricot --platform=mswin32
```

Answer (score 2):

An additional note that others may find useful, from my recent attempt to install on Windows using the Ruby devkit:

To install the devkit, you extract the bin and devkit directories to your Ruby directory which will place a few files in your Ruby bin and a devkit directory in your Ruby directory.  Then, per the instructions, you set the proper location for mingw in the fstab file.

In my case, some gems, namely Hpricot and Ruby-Debug19, would not install on my system even with the devkit installed properly  because of an error creating the makefile.  I ended up installing the latest version of mingw separately from SourceForge, then changed the fstab file within the "`ruby19/devkit/msys/1.0.11/etc`" directory to point to the directory where I installed mingw.  Both gems then installed correctly.

Answer (score -3):

Execute the following command:

```
gem install hpricot
```

Comment: Using RubyInstaller on Windows this fails with a message like `Error installing hpricot: The 'hpricot' native gem requires installed build tools.`