# "sudo apt-get install ruby-dev" in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to install the Ruby development tools on Windows, essentially the same command as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12552948/6474013.

I have already tried to use Sudowin but it's doesn't work for the ruby command prompt. I use RailsInstaller with Ruby 2.1.8

Comment: You need to install ruby developer tools.
[Visit this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856087/sudo-apt-get-install-ruby-dev-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install the compiler toolchain to compile certain gems on Windows, you can install the [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) as an Addon to Ruby Installer.

If you installed a Rails Installer package from http://railsinstaller.org/, this should already be included into the package.

Comment: I know, but for example when i type "gem install curses" :
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curses:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
**extconf.rb failed***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.//..
Also in RubyMine when i try install gems have thar eror "Native compilation failed.Please make sure that you have Ruby DevKit installed"

Comment: Well, in order to install gems which interface with external libraries, you have to install these external libraries to your system. In the case of `curses`, you do need to install the curses library and their development headers to your computer